# Read GUID value from database

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Please see the code:

```
var roleId = from r in _eStoreDbContext.UserModel where r.UserName == userName select r.RoleId;
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(roleId.ToString()))
{
    return false;
}

Guid g = new Guid();
Guid.TryParse(roleId.ToString(), out g);
```

While executing query I'm getting Guid value, But converting it into GUID, getting 000XXXX.
Please find attached the debugging screen.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`roleId` is `IQueryable<T>` (that is just query definition, not result of query execution, and definitely not first item from results). When you call `roleId.ToString()` you get type name, which is obviously cannot be parsed to Guid.

I think you need to get first or default `roleId` from database:

```
var roleId = _eStoreDbContext.UserModel 
                 .Where(u => u.UserName == userName)
                 .Select(u => u.RoleId)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Further actions depend on what type `RoleId` has. If its nullable Guid, then you can compare `roleId` with null to check if id was found. If its non-nullable, then compare result with `Guid.Empty`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is, judging from the screenshot, is that `var roleId` variable is actually an `IEnumerable<string>`, and not a single string!
What you need to do is call `.SingleOrDefault()` on the result of your query, then you can (try)parse is with `Guid.TryParse`, i.e.:

```
var roleId = (from r in _eStoreDbContext.UserModel 
              where r.UserName == userName select 
              r.RoleId).SingleOrDefault();
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Simply leave out the creation of a new `Guid`-object. Instead of:

```
    Guid g = new Guid();
    Guid.TryParse(roleId.ToString(), out g);
```

just do this:

```
    Guid g;
    Guid.TryParse(roleId.ToString(), out g);
```

Be sure to pass in a string representing a `Guid`-object.